# Tensorflow, program stuck on sess.run( ) function

Tags: python, tensorflow

i am new to Tensorflow, and i meet a problem. When my program reaches `x_batch = sess.run(X_mb)`, it is stuck (So, it can print 1 and 2, but cannot print 4. I guess it is a endless loop). I print `X_mb`'s value, and the result is  `Tensor("batch:0", shape=(32, 39), dtype=float32)`. Can any one can help me? Thx!
mb_size = 32, g's shape is [60366 , 39].

Updated Code:

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, X_dim])

def sample_z(m, n):
    return np.random.uniform(-1., 1., size=[m, n])

g = tf.unstack(data, num = 60366, axis = 0)
X_mb, *_ = tf.train.batch(g ,mb_size, capacity = 60366)
sess = tf.train.MonitoredSession()


i = 0

for it in range(2000):
    #print(1)
    for _ in range(5):
        #print(2)       

        #print(X_mb)
        x_batch = sess.run(X_mb)
       # print(4)
        _, D_loss_curr, _ = sess.run(
            [D_solver, D_loss, clip_D],
            feed_dict={X: x_batch, z: sample_z(mb_size, z_dim)}
        )

    _, G_loss_curr = sess.run(
        [G_solver, G_loss],
        feed_dict={z: sample_z(mb_size, z_dim)}
    )
```

Here is the error message:

```
runfile('/Users/franklan123/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='/Users/franklan123/.spyder-py3')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-4-6af95f06eb7f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/franklan123/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='/Users/franklan123/.spyder-py3')

  File "/Users/franklan123/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 688, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/franklan123/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 101, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/franklan123/.spyder-py3/temp.py", line 48, in <module>
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, X_dim])

  File "/Users/franklan123/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1530, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)

  File "/Users/franklan123/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1954, in _placeholder
    name=name)

  File "/Users/franklan123/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)

  File "/Users/franklan123/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2458, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()

  File "/Users/franklan123/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2181, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")

RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no endless loop, tf.train.batch creates **queues** and you have to run queue runners to get any data. Otherwise, when you execute sess.run your code just hangs on queue.dequeue() operation (as there is no thread actually putting data into queue).

Simple solution:

1. Move the X_mb line **before** session creation (this modified a graph!)
2. Change tf.Session to tf.train.MonitoredSession (which will run queues for you, otherwise you would have to run them manually + MonitoredSession finalizes graph so you will avoid errors like the one above in the future). Once you do this - remove the line with global initializers (MonitoredSession initializes for you too).

Comment: Hi, i did what you say, but i got a RuntimeError (Graph is finalised and cannot be modified)

Comment: As said in the answer - this will finalize your graph, you **cannot** modify your graph afterwards (and this is how TF code should be written). Maybe you forgot to remove initializer?

Comment: Here is my code:  g = tf.unstack(data, num = 60366, axis = 0)
X_mb, *_ = tf.train.batch(g ,mb_size, capacity = 60366)
sess = tf.train.MonitoredSession()
i = 0

for it in range(2000):
    for _ in range(5):
              
        x_batch = sess.run(X_mb)
      
        _, D_loss_curr, _ = sess.run(
            [D_solver, D_loss, clip_D],
            feed_dict={X: x_batch, z: sample_z(mb_size, z_dim)}
        )

Comment: and what is "sample_z"? I guess another thing which modifies a graph?

Comment: def sample_z(m, n):
    return np.random.uniform(-1., 1., size=[m, n])

Comment: Can you please update the question, with the new code + where the error is exactly being thrown?

Comment: you are running it in notebook or something like this (which keeps previous graph in memory). run it properly from "clean" kernel, or directly through python.